# Divergence of $\sum \left(\frac{k-2}{k}\right)^k$ via $\frac{1}{e^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function

I want to prove that:
$$ \sum \left(\frac{k-2}{k}\right)^k$$ is divergent.

My approach would be to look at the limit of general term and notice that this goes to $e^{-2}$. How would I prove this?
I have been trying to rearrange the term like:

$$\left(\frac{k-2 +2}{k-2}\right)^{-k}=\left(1+\frac{2}{k-2}\right)^{-k}$$
But I do not see how to get the "square" in the exponent too.

I want to use the fact that $(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n \rightarrow e$

Comment: Unfortunate the inequality symbols are reversed: $0 \leqslant (k-2)/k < 1$, then the $k$-th power is still less than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left(\frac k {k-2}\right)^k = \left(1 + \frac 2{k-2}\right)^{k-2} \left(1 + \frac 2{k-2}\right)^2 = \left(\left(1 + \frac 1{(k-2)/2}\right)^{(k-2)/2}\right)^{\color{red}2} \left(1 + \frac 2{k-2}\right)^2
$$
then taking the reciprocal.

#### UPDATE

If you want to use $\lim_n (1+1/n)^n = \mathrm e$ only, we actually need to justify that
$$
\lim_n \left(1 + \frac 2n\right)^n = \mathrm e^2. 
$$
To do this, note that
$$
b_n = \left(1 +\frac 1 n\right)^{2n} = \left(1 + \frac 2n + \frac 1{n^2}\right)^n = \left(\frac {1+2n +n^2}{n^2}\right)^n \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty} \mathrm e^2, 
$$
while 
$$
a_n =\left(1 + \frac 2n\right)^n = \left(\frac {2+n}{n}\right)^n = \left(\frac {n^2+2n}{n^2}\right), 
$$
and 
$$
1 \leqslant \frac {b_n}{a_n} = \left(\frac {1+2n+n^2}{n^2+2n}\right)^n = \left(1+\frac 1{n^2+2n}\right)^n = \left( \left(1 + \frac 1{n^2+2n}\right)^{n(n+2)}\right)^{1/(n+2)} \leqslant \mathrm e^{1/(n+2)} \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty} 1, 
$$
thus $\lim_n b_n/a_n = 1$ by squeezing theorem. Since $\lim_n b_n = \mathrm e^2$, using the arithmetic operation we have 
$$
\lim_n a_n =\left. \lim_n b_n \middle/ \lim_n \frac {b_n}{a_n} \right. = \mathrm e^2, 
$$
as we desire.

Comment: thank you for answering my question, this is the technique I wished to learn, great!

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo You are welcome. However you should notice that I actually used $\lim_{x\to +\infty} (1 + x^{-1})^x = \mathrm e$, because $(k-2)/2$ might not be integers.

Comment: This then goes to $e \cdot 1$ as desired :D nice usage of an index shift too.

Comment: fair point. that is something to think about.

Comment: I like your edit

Answer (score 2):

$\left(\frac {k-2} k\right)^{k}=\left(1-\frac 2 k\right)^{k} \to e^{-2}$. [ Write $(1-\frac 1 n)^{n}$ as $a_n^{-n/{n-1}}$ where $a_n=(1+\frac 1 {n-1})^{n-1}$ and conclude that $(1-\frac 1n )^{n} \to \frac 1 e$. For $(1-\frac 2n  )^{n}$ split the sequence int0 even and odd terms. The argument is slightly lengthy but not difficult].

Comment: you use some general formula $(1+ \frac{a}{n})^n \rightarrow e^a$  here , I know, this is how I know I should get $e^{-2}$, but this is not a proof and we have not derived this formula yet.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Have you already proved that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{f(n)}\right)^{f(n)}=e\;\;\text{ whenever $f$ is a function such that}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\infty\;?$$

Comment: No, we will cover functions in a couple of  weeks, one step at a time unfortunately ;D but I just got to pause and enjoy it too sometimes.

Comment: Well, the function $\;f\;$ above **is a sequence** in fact...

Comment: Somebody is downvoting with such an ease. Both this answer, which imo is better than the other ones, and the other answer which also correct though pretty short.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo I have improved my answer but you will have to do some hard work based on my hints.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use that

$$\left(1+\frac{2}{k-2}\right)^{-k}=e^{-k \log\left(1+\frac{2}{k-2}\right)}\to e^{-2}$$

indeed by standard limits

$$-k \log\left(1+\frac{2}{k-2}\right)=\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{2}{k-2}\right)}{\frac2{k-2}}\frac{-2k}{k-2}\to -2$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes of course you are right, it’s a correct extension of ratio test when it tends to $1^+$. Sorry for my stupid remark!

Answer (score 0):

With $m:=n-2$,

$$\left(\frac{n-2}n\right)^n=\frac1{\left(\left(1+\dfrac2m\right)^{m/2}\right)^2\left(1+\dfrac2m\right)^2}$$

and as this expression has the limit $e^{-2}$, the general term does not tend to zero.